# How to resolve domain names of remote servers while ssh port-forwarding

Tags: mongodb, go, ssh, portforwarding, mgo

I am trying to connect to remote mongodb servers using port forwarding. In mgo.DialInfo, the dial server will return a connection (of type `*net.Conn`) to the intermediary host and the `Addrs` would be a string of remote mongodb servers' addresses (a set of seed servers). My question is, if I give the remote IP addresses of these servers, the program works fine and I am able to connect to the remote mongodb servers but since, the IP addresses can change I want to give the domain names of the servers, say *mongodbserver1* and *mongodbserver2* and when I give that, the program hangs. As far as I understood, the program is trying to resolve the domain names on my local machine which won't work and they need to be resolved on the intermediary host. I want to know how I can do that.

In terms of code, the following works fine,

```
dialinfo := mgo.DialInfo{
    Addrs:    {"1.2.3.45","1.2.3.56"}
    Database: Mongo1,
    Username: User,
    Password: Pwd,
    Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
    DialServer: func(addr *mgo.ServerAddr) (net.Conn, error) {
        conn, err := connectToCluster("172.12.13.145")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("couldn't connect to the cluster, trying again..")
            return nil, err
        }
        remote, err := conn.Dial("tcp", addr.String())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("couldn't connect to the mongodb server:", addr.String())
        }
        return remote, err
    },
}
session, err = mgo.DialWithInfo(dialinfo)
```

but the one below doesn't work

```
  dialinfo := mgo.DialInfo{
    Addrs:    {"mongodbserver1","mongodbserver2"}
    Database: Mongo1,
    Username: User,
    Password: Pwd,
    Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
    DialServer: func(addr *mgo.ServerAddr) (net.Conn, error) {
        conn, err := connectToCluster("172.12.13.145")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("couldn't connect to the cluster, trying again..")
            return nil, err
        }
        remote, err := conn.Dial("tcp", addr.String())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("couldn't connect to the mongodb server:", addr.String())
        }
        return remote, err
    },
}
session, err = mgo.DialWithInfo(dialinfo)
```

Answer (score -1):

Configure name resolution to work on your machine.  This could mean adding test entries to `/etc/hosts` (if you're using *nix). Or you could add an entry for your production DNS server to `/etc/resolv.conf` (again, assuming *nix).

Comment: I want the changes to be made inside the code rather than changing the /etc/hosts file so that whoever runs this code, doesnt have to manually make changes to any file.

Comment: I don't understand what you're wanting. You want to use a domain name, but you also want to hard-code the IP address?  It feels like you're asking for contradictory things.

Comment: No. That's not what I want. What I meant is that, if I run this code( with domain name and not ip address) on any machine, that machine should resolve the domain name automatically and there shouldn't be any manual configuration needed.

Comment: @user1851006: So you want your Go program to magically configure DNS for you?

Comment: yes. I am wondering if the net package of golang has such feature.